# Primary decomposition in a quotient ring

Tags: commutative-algebra

> Suppose $I$ and $J$ are two ideals in a polynomial ring $R=\mathbb{Q}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, what's the relation between the primary decomposition of $I$ in the quotient ring $R/J$ and the primary decomposition of $I+J$ in $R$? In particular it can be assumed $J$ is prime.

The question is raised because all the algorithms for the computation of primary decomposition assume a polynomial ring.

Thanks.

Comment: Oh right. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Apparently I don't have enough *reputation* to upvote your answer... What a newbie I am. So I simply accepted it. Thanks for your answer! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$I+J=∩_i Q_i$   primary decomposition in $R$  ⇒  $(I+J)/J=∩_i (Q_i /J)$  primary decomposition in $R/J$, and viceversa.